# Check a custom security number

Tags: php, regex

I try to check, if there is a custom security number in an ocr string with a regex. I never know the correct number. I just want to find out if a custom security number exists in a string.

For example:

```
// 81130790K038 (always 12 characters, 8x 0-9, 1x A-Z, 3x 0-9)
```

Here is what i have, but it dont match the correct ssn:

```
// At the end there is: " 8 11 30 7 90K0 38 "    
$example_str = "SGA/SIE 405801/11700/69 Personal? Nr IGe?urlsdalun smfltpgngen?mßxllige .If .lr Juni 2 01 8 0 3 .0 7 .2 01 8 Blatt 1 0 0 0 69 1 3,0 7190 4 . roilcfessmn Fretbetrag am. Frerbetrag mtl.? DSA Glettzone lät.ng? VJ Ur1 üb. unAnspl. Url.Tg.gen. IResturlaub SV-Nummer .kk oJ 8 11 30 7 90K0 38 ";

if(preg_match('/([\s]{1})([0-9\s]{8,16})([A-Z0-9a-z]{1})([0-9\s]{3,6})([\s]{1})/', $example_str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
{
   print_r($matches);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] Array
        (
            [0] 1 0 0 0 69 1 
            [1] 133
        )

    [1] Array
        (
            [0]  
            [1] 133
        )
    [2] Array
        (
            [0] 1 0 0 0 
            [1] 134
        )
    [3] Array
        (
            [0] 6
            [1] 142
        )
    [4] Array
        (
            [0] 9 1
            [1] 143
        )
    [5] Array
        (
            [0]  
            [1] 146
        )
)
```

Can someone help me with the regex, please?

Best regards, 
olli

**UPDATE:** *preg_match_all* helps me, thank you.

Comment: Where is `81130790K038` in the example string?

Comment: looks like you may have a false positive, and no global flag. try using `preg_match_all`

Comment: It can have spaces between. In example string its at the end.

Answer (score 2):

According to the format, you can use this pattern:

```
(?<!\S)(?:[0-9] *){8}[A-Z](?: *[0-9]){3}(?!\S)
```

`(?<!\S)` checks there isn't a character that isn't a whitespace before and `(?!\S)` does the same after.

If you want you can replace each literal space with `\h` (character class for horizontal white-spaces) or `\s` for any kind of white-spaces.